# Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 HUD support

Tags: gnome, hud

I am really fan of a gnome shell and Ubuntu. I am using current Ubuntu gnome 15.04 and because I’m not the mouse-type-of-person, I want to use HUD.

Is HUD supported by Ubuntu gnome?